# Conditional Formatting in a Razor Index View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to conditionally add a CSS `background-color` to a set of table rows, based on how close the item's expiry date is. Thirty days or less should be red, 90 - 31 days amber and the rest green. (I'm putting the red in first, once this is working I'll go back and do the amber/green rows).

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    int daysLeft = (item.ExpiryDate - DateTime.Today).Days;

    if (daysLeft <= 30)
    { 
         <tr style="background-color:Red">
    }
    else
    {
        <tr>
    }

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupplierName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpiryDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InceptionDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

When I run this page, I get a YSOD saying the `@foreach` block is missing its closing `}`, but as far as I can see they are matched so I'm assuming the *actual* problem is something else.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Razor requires that tags directly inside code blocks be balanced and well-formed.
Therefore, all of the code after the first opening `<tr>` tag is actually parsed as markup, so that the final `}` just closes the `if`.

To fix that, you can force Razor to ignore the tag by prefixing the line with `@:`.

Alternatively, you can get rid of the `if` entirely and write

```
string style = daysLeft <= 30 ? "background-color:Red" : null;
<tr style="@style">
    ...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 31):

Use the conditional operator

bool condition ? *true_expression* : *false_expression*;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    int daysLeft = (item.ExpiryDate - DateTime.Today).Days;

    <tr style="@(daysleft < 30 ? "Background-color:red" : "")">   
.....
}
```